# apt-cacher-ng is having some issues with replying to "sudo apt update" from Ubuntu client

Tags: apt, http-proxy, ubuntu-mate, apt-cacher

It worked ok with Ubuntu 18.04 but on Ubuntu 20.04 the issue with apt-cacher-ng is like this,

```
$ sudo apt update 
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe Translation-en
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [8,600 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages [4,624 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe Translation-en [5,131 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe Translation-en [5,131 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  403  Forbidden file type or location [IP: 192.168.17.34 3142]
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Fetched 15.2 MB in 1min 15s (203 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/cnf/Commands-amd64  403 Forbidden file type or location [IP: 192.168.17.34 3142]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

But without the proxy, the `sudo apt update` is like

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease         
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [29.2 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [8,600 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages [4,624 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe Translation-en [5,131 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [264 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                            
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9,164 B]                                                                                                                                                                                        
Fetched 567 kB in 31s (18.4 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

And my supported file type pattern on `/etc/apt-cacher-ng/acng.conf` is

```
PfilePattern = .(.d?deb|.db|.rpm|.drpm|.dsc|.tar(.gz|.bz2|.lzma|.xz|.zst)(.gpg)?|.diff(.gz|.bz2|.lzma|.zst|.xz)|.jigdo|.template|changelog|copyright|.udeb|.debdelta|.diff/..gz|(Devel)?ReleaseAnnouncement(\?.)?|[a-f0-9]+-(susedata|updateinfo|primary|deltainfo).xml.gz|fonts/(final/)?[a-z]+32.exe(\?download.)?|/dists/./installer-[^/]+/[0-9][^/]+/images/.)$
```

and here is the `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-MATE 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Beta amd64 (20200402)]/ focal main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports multiverse restricted main universe
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed multiverse restricted main universe #Not for humans during development stage of release focal
```

And also the issue is with only 20.04 as I do not encounter it with 18.04 (was ok for real machine and VM likewise). And the issue is only with the `sudo apt update`, if I update the repo directly and then use **apt-chacher-ng** as ***proxy*** to download the packages, no issues. So where it is going wrong exactly?

Comment: Also works fine on debian buster.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing this `apt update` error on 20.04 through apt-cacher-ng as well, though the `apt upgrade` seems to still work.  noticed the files on the server had .**xz** extensions, if that is a clue.

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/cnf/

```
Index of /ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/cnf

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory        -
[   ]   Commands-amd64.xz   2020-06-03 12:29    2.6K
[   ]   Commands-i386.xz    2020-06-03 12:29    1.7K
[DIR]   by-hash/    2019-10-25 05:33    -
```

I haven't been able to identify a fix yet... Tried to add this to `acng.cnf` (to mark it as "volatile") but not sure if it addressed the problem, since the problem went away on the client after I commented out apt proxy and performed an `apt update`

```
#PfilePatternEx: .*(\.xz)
VfilePatternEx: .*(\.xz)$
SVfilePatternEx: .*(\.xz)$
```